# What is the best strategy for dealing with redirects in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects

On my website, I redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, and from non-WWW to WWW. The canonical pages are the HTTPS/WWW versions.

These preferences are specified in the page headers (link rel="canonical") as well as in the XML site map.

But then in Google Search Console the non-HTTPS versions seem to manifest a "Validation Failed" problem with the message "Page with redirect: These pages aren't indexed or served on Google."

What is the correct strategy for dealing with these? Just ignore them?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have been ignoring them.  You can remove them using the Removal Tool.  But they might come back.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot with the error message?  Validation errors are usually with problems adding your site to search console, not with specific URL once you have add them.

Comment: @stephen-ostermiller I added a screenshot

Comment: What's in the See more that it links to?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "See Details" just shows a few examples of the HTTP versions of the pages which are redirecting to the HTTPS versions. That's it.

Comment: Short answer is, yes, you can usually ignore them. Most of the time, it deals with canonical pages. The reasoning is that non-canonical pages redirect to the canonical one, therefore, Google won't index both versions (to avoid duplicates). You should check a couple, and if that's the case, you can safely ignore them.